# Separators for author group (IF conditon)

Tags: macros, conditionals, titles, loops

I am new to LaTeX, just a beginner, basically a Perl developer.

I have created a LaTeX file

```
\begin{document}

\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

\end{document}
```

Now my need is to define LaTeX commands so that the output should appear as below

> Name1 K. C. G., Name11 Y. Q. and Name111 C.-Z. Some title Text - 995.

`\iname` - Person Name will repeat several times
`\isurname` - Surname of a person
`\ifname` - First Name of a person

`\iname` will repeat any number of times, say 1 to ...

If only one `\iname` found inside `\cont`, display should be like the below

> Name1 K. C. G. Some title Text - 995.

If only two `\iname` found inside `\cont`, display should be like the below

> Name1 K. C. G. and Name11 Y. Q. Some title Text - 995.

If more than two `\iname` found inside \cont, display should be like the below (and should come after last `\iname`)

> Name1 K. C. G., Name11 Y. Q. and Name111 C.-Z. Some title Text - 995.

I can define input for `\iname` separated by commas, but I don't know how to write a macro to define `\iname` with different outputs based on the if condition.

I hope to have clearly explained my doubt.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Cross-posted on [LaTeX community](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=23873)

Answer (score 5):

Your input is *very* specific, and so is this answer. It assumes an `\isurname`-`\ifname` structure inside `\iname`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{namecntr}\newcounter{curname}
\providecommand{\iname}[1]{}
\providecommand{\isurname}[1]{}
\providecommand{\ifname}[1]{}
\providecommand{\ititles}[1]{}
\providecommand{\ipage}[1]{}
\newcommand{\cont}[1]{{%
  \setcounter{namecntr}{0}\setcounter{curname}{0}% Restart counters
  \renewcommand*{\iname}{\stepcounter{namecntr}}% Set namecntr
  #1% Count number of names
  \renewcommand*{\iname}{\stepcounter{curname}% Set names
    \ifnum\value{curname}>1
      \ifnum\value{curname}<\value{namecntr}
        \unskip, 
      \else
        \unskip, and
      \fi\fi}%
  \renewcommand*{\isurname}[1]{##1}% Print surname
  \renewcommand*{\ifname}[1]{~##1}% Print first name
  \renewcommand*{\ititles}[1]{\unskip\space##1}% Print title
  \renewcommand*{\ipage}[1]{~-~##1}% Print page(s)
  #1% Process "list"
}}
\begin{document}

% One author
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% No authors
\cont{\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Two authors
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Three authors
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Three authors with no page
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}}

% Four authors
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Four authors with no title
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ipage{995}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, both the codings working very fine for me, it saved me a lot of time writing coding in perl, once again Thanks a lot

Comment: @SathishV: Consider accepting one of the solutions as the answer. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)

Answer (score 3):

Please check whether the following MWE suits your requirement:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{name}
\def\auCon{\unskip,\space}
\def\auAndCon{\unskip\space and\space}
\def\auStop{\space}
\long\def\cont#1{\setcounter{name}{0}%
  \expandafter\let\csname iname@ititles\endcsname\@undefined
  \expandafter\let\csname iname@ipage\endcsname\@undefined
  \def\isurname##1{\expandafter\gdef\csname iname@isurname@\thename\endcsname{##1}}%
  \def\ifname##1{\expandafter\gdef\csname iname@ifname@\thename\endcsname{##1}}%
  \def\iname##1{\stepcounter{name}##1}%
  \def\ititles##1{\expandafter\gdef\csname iname@ititles\endcsname{##1}}%
  \def\ipage##1{\expandafter\gdef\csname iname@ipage\endcsname{##1}}%
  #1%
  \@tempcnta=0%
  \@tempcntb=\thename%
  \advance\@tempcntb by -1%
  \loop\ifnum\@tempcnta<\thename%
    \advance\@tempcnta by 1%
    \xdef\myname{\the\@tempcnta}%
    \csname iname@isurname@\myname\endcsname\space%
    \csname iname@ifname@\myname\endcsname%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta<\@tempcntb%
      \auCon\else\ifnum\@tempcnta=\@tempcntb%
      \auAndCon\else\auStop\fi\fi%
  \repeat%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname iname@ititles\endcsname\relax\else%
  \textit{\csname iname@ititles\endcsname}\space\fi%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname iname@ipage\endcsname\relax\else%
  \textbf{\csname iname@ipage\endcsname}\fi\par
}
\makeatother

% One author
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% No authors
\cont{\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Two authors
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Three authors
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Three authors with no page
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}}

% Four authors
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ititles{Some title Text}\ipage{995}}

% Four authors with no title
\cont{\iname{\isurname{Name1}\ifname{K. C. G.}}\iname{\isurname{Name11}\ifname{Y. Q.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\iname{\isurname{Name111}\ifname{C.-Z.}}\ipage{995}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, both the codings working very fine for me, it saved me a lot of time writing coding in perl, once again Thanks a lot, Tamila Boss neenga, me too Tamil

Comment: @SathishV I am a Malayali, knows konjam konjam Tamil  :-)